# Android - How to get Path object of an SVG programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas, android-canvas

I'm trying to mask on canvas in Android. I can do this to for specific shapes as follows.

```
  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas );
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(getCollageBackgroundColor());
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    Path clipPath = new Path();
    clipPath.addRoundRect(new 
    RectF(getPiecePadding()+100,getPiecePadding()+100,getCollageWidth()- 
    getPiecePadding()-100,getCollageHeight()-getPiecePadding()-100),500,530 , 
       Path.Direction.CW);
    clipPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);
    canvas.drawPath(clipPath,mPaint);
  }
```

The code above is masking in a circular shape. I want to be able to do this with any vectorDrawable file. Is there a way I can get this drawable's Path object in onDraw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I answer my own question for the benefit of people who have the same problem in the future.

My solution is not a direct solution. I am copying the path string in SVG.
I found a library called Sharp. This library is able to generate a path object from the string. Here is my code:

```
String s= "M0,0h24v24h-24z";
Path path = Sharp.loadPath(s);
```

Comment: I fail to find that library on the internet. Any hints?

Comment: @arkascha https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp